# Use Grep (or any other cmd line tool) to count Lines that contain different pattern

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am experimenting with OpenMP, and I am just trying to write a small shell script to count of the number of lines that each thread outputs. And simply spit out each count.
I started getting into it, and starting having to a write a for loop with either a hard coded or parameterized upper bound, and grep -c REG_EX, I also tried to use sed to clean up the extra output first to make greps job easier, but it is not working like I would like

```
EXAMPLE PROGRAM OUT(SCRIPT INPUT)

Output to STDOUT (I can obviously pipe into sort first):
Thread 0: EXTRA OUTPUT
Thread 0: EXTRA OUTPUT
Thread 2: EXTRA OUTPUT
Thread 3: EXTRA OUTPUT
Thread 0: EXTRA OUTPUT
Thread 1: EXTRA OUTPUT
.
.
.
```

ETC

All I need is:

```
Thread 0: #repeats
Thread 1: #repeats
.
.
.
Thread n: #repeats
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pipe your output into this:

```
grep -o "Thread [0-9]*" | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $3 ":", $1}'
```

This will first reduce each line to just the part before the colon (so that every line a given thread outputs is identical), count how many lines each thread output, and rearrange the output of `uniq` to match your sample output.

Comment: Thank-you that answered the implicit issue I was having too of simply trying to get the Thread [0-9]*: part, I do not know why that was not working for me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had a million and a half other things to do and I am just getting back to this.
I wanted to confirm it before I accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of grep to wc ("Word count") which, with a -l flag, will count the number of lines:

```
grep needle haystack.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: `grep -c` has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {0..10}; do
   str="Thread $i:"
   cnt=$(grep -c "$str" input)
   echo "$str $cnt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` alone is enough. This should work for any number of threads..

```
awk -F ":| " '{a[$2]++; if($2>max) max=$2;} END {for (i=0; i<=max; i++) print "Thread "i": "a[i]}' output
```

For your example, it will produce..

```
Thread 0: 3
Thread 1: 1
Thread 2: 1
Thread 3: 1
```

Comment: @perreal- Sorry, din't get you.

Comment: sorry, you don't need cat is what I meant

Comment: @perreal- Oh yes, actually I tested it by making a file named `output`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the lines that **don't** match a pattern, you use

`grep -v 'pattern' file`

To get the lines that do,

`grep 'pattern' file`

To count,

`grep -v 'foo' bar.txt | wc -l`   (# of lines that don't match 'foo')

`grep 'foo' bar.txt | wc -l`      (# of lines that do match 'foo')

This seems to be what the title asks for, but I have to admit, your post confused me

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I was asking how to count lines that began with different patterns

Answer (score 0):

All you need is awk:

```
<infile awk '{ h[$1" "$2]++ } END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }'
```

Output:

```
Thread 0: 3
Thread 1: 1
Thread 2: 1
Thread 3: 1
```

If you only want to count lines beginning with "Thread" prepend the first block like this: `$1 == "Thread" { h[$1" "$2]++ } ...`.